# Does removing an object from an array run the object's dealloc method?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, memory

Working in Objective C here. Suppose I have an array named `fooArray`. Each element in this `fooArray` is an object...we'll call them `barObject1`, `barObject2`, `barObject3`, etc. Now each of these objects has several properties which are taking up memory. Now, imagine that I clear out one of these objects from `fooArray` using something to the extent of:

```
[fooArray removeObjectAtIndex:0]
```

Now, does this actually delete the object? Or does it merely take it out of the array, leaving the object and its properties to float around in memory?

This isn't directly related to any project I'm working on, just simply trying to understand how it's working.

thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An array retains the objects it contains. Removing the object from the array will call `release` on the object. Then, if the object has a retain count of `0`, it will be deallocated.

Comment: thanks! Something I've always wondered :) I'll accept your answer as soon as it lets me.